# Vanilla JavaScript Next & prev Navigation

Tags: javascript

I traying to make testimonials slider with next & prev buttons, but unfortunately can't make it work perfectly.
tried many things but there is something wrong with my code
Need your help
Note: I still learning Javascript.

Here is my code:

```js
    let nextBtn = document.querySelector('.testi-nav .next');
    let prevBtn = document.querySelector('.testi-nav .prev');
    let testiBox = document.querySelectorAll('.testi-box')
    nextBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    testiBox.forEach(testi => {
        testi.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block'
        testi.style.display = 'none';
    })
    })
    prevBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    testiBox.forEach(testi => {
            testi.prevElementSibling.style.display = 'block';
            testi.style.display = 'none';
        })
     })
```

```css
    .testi-box {
    padding: 80px;
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px rgba(196, 194, 196, 0.815);
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    }
    .testi-box:first-child {
     display: block;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="testimonial">
        <div class="testi-nav">
            <span class="nav-button prev"><i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i></span>
            <span class="nav-button next"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="testi-box">
                <div class="testi-img">
                    <div class="person">
                        <img src="imgs/Testimonial/person/tmc (1).jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="testi-text">
                    <p>"Lorem ipsum"</p>
                    <p class="person-name">UI/UX Designer <span>John David</span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="testi-box">
                <div class="testi-img">
                    <div class="person">
                        <img src="imgs/Testimonial/person/tmc (3).jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="testi-text">
                    <p>"Lorem ipsum"</p>
                    <p class="person-name">UI/UX Designer <span>John David</span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="testi-box">
                <div class="testi-img">
                    <div class="person">
                        <img src="imgs/Testimonial/person/tmc (4).png" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="testi-text">
                    <p>"Lorem ipsum"</p>
                    <p class="person-name">UI/UX Designer <span>John David</span></p>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: What does "can't make it work" and "something wrong" mean? What are the specific problems that you are experiencing? What ***exactly*** is supposed to happen? Are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: I have 3 divs (.testi-box) I just want to when I clicked next go to next (div.testi-box).
example:
when div[1] appears when click next go to div[2], And if I click prev go to last div[3]

Comment: That's what you want to happen. I'm asking what is actually happening. You say something is wrong. Are you getting errors? What is the code that you've tried that isn't working?

Comment: What happens is when I clicked next its jump to the last div and when I clicked next or prev again there is nothing happens its freezes on the last div and I got this error on console :
main.js:161 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at main.js:161
    at NodeList.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLSpanElement.<anonymous> (main.js:160)

Comment: Ok, right now your posted code doesn't include any previous or next buttons so we can't replicate your issue and help. Please updated your question's code to include what you are trying.

Comment: <div class="testimonial">
        <div class="testi-nav">
            <span class="nav-button prev"><i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i></span>
            <span class="nav-button next"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></span>
        </div>
its on first lines on my HTML code

Comment: No, please read my comments carefully. Edit your existing question and add this code to it so we can have the complete code you are working with in one place, not the comments.

Comment: The code I commented its already on a question if you please take  a look again to HTML section in my question you will find it in first lines.

Comment: But since you’re not including the full code, those “buttons” don’t appear here so we have nothing to try to click on. You should at least put an “x” in the <I> elements.

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest a different approach (this is an example not meant to directly mimic your code):

```js
//store your data as an array of objects
const data = [
  {name: "Name1", url: "url1"},
  {name: "Name2", url: "url2"},
  {name: "Name3", url: "url3"},
  {name: "Name4", url: "url4"},
  {name: "Name5", url: "url5"}
]

//create an index variable
let index = 0; 

//store your elements
let img = document.getElementById("image");
let name = document.getElementById("name"); 

//create a render function that updates your elements with current index
const render = () => {
  img.setAttribute("src",data[index].url);
  name.textContent = data[index].name;
}

//make prev on click that lowers index down to 0
const prev = () => {
  if(index > 0){
    index -= 1;
    render(index);
  }
}

//make next on click that raises index up to last
const next = () => {
  if(index < data.length -1){
    index += 1;
    render();
  }
}
```

```html
<!--  only render one set of data -->
<img src="url1" id="image" /> 
<div id="name"> Name1 </div>

<button onclick="prev()">prev</button>
<button onclick="next()">next</button>
```

Comment: There's no need for Pens or Fiddles. Just create a Stack Snippet right here in your answer.

Comment: Ty, I wasn't aware how to do that.